# Kusto Query Language: semantic error on user-defined functions

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

Hello StackOverflow community.

I recently came up with an interesting tutorial/game about KQL, a I am trying to solve puzzles proposed on the site.
One of them makes use of the following function to display a map

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "Virtual tour starts here", skipvalidation = "true") VirtualTourLink(lat:real, lon:real) { 
    print Link=strcat('https://www.google.com/maps/@', lat, ',', lon, ',4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192')}
```

I am trying to use this function with some known values (see example below)

```
nyc_trees
| invoke VirtualTourLink(lat=40.6777207, lon=-73.86205414)
```

However, the KQL compiler prompts an error stating that the function only accepts two arguments.
Do you have clues why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

The body of the function is basically a *print* statement.
*print* is a tabular operator (which yield a single row); therefore, you should treat the function as a table:

```
VirtualTourLink(lat=40.6777207, lon=-73.86205414)
```

| Link |
| --- |
| https://www.google.com/maps/@40.6777207,-73.86205414,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |

P.S.
If you want to execute the function over rows of the table you can redefine it like this (remove the *print* so the function will return a scalar):

```
.create-or-alter function with (docstring = "Virtual tour starts here", skipvalidation = "true") VirtualTourLink(lat:real, lon:real) { 
    strcat('https://www.google.com/maps/@', lat, ',', lon, ',4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192')}
```

The usage will look like this:

```
nyc_trees
| sample 5
| project tree_id
         ,latitude
         ,longitude
         ,VTL = VirtualTourLink(lat=latitude, lon=longitude)
```

| tree_id | latitude | longitude | VTL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 180683 | 40.72309177 | -73.84421522 | https://www.google.com/maps/@40.72309177,-73.84421522,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |
| 200540 | 40.79411067 | -73.81867946 | https://www.google.com/maps/@40.79411067,-73.81867946,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |
| 204026 | 40.71758074 | -73.9366077 | https://www.google.com/maps/@40.71758074,-73.9366077,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |
| 204337 | 40.71353749 | -73.93445616 | https://www.google.com/maps/@40.71353749,-73.93445616,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |
| 189565 | 40.66677776 | -73.97597938 | https://www.google.com/maps/@40.66677776,-73.97597938,4a,75y,32.0h,79.0t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s-1P!2e0!5s20191101T000000!7i16384!8i8192 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/kvchr46qwqbz7qek2dqe0x.northeurope/databases/MyDatabase?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8urTI4vKUpNLeblqlEoTswtyElVMAWxC4rys1KTSxRAkvGZKbxcCjCgk5NYkllSmpKKIpafl44hGBbio2CrEJZZVFKamBOSX1rkk5mXrQHUbgszQkcBqNEWrlkTANq099ePAAAA)